# How do I update posts in real time?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to update my post array in real time and show a new results when a document is added. I know that I have to setup a snapshot listener however I have failed in my efforts to factor it into my code.

My code is below.

```
    func fetchPosts(completion: @escaping([Post]) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
        .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            let posts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
            completion(posts)
        }
}
```

Observed object is already setup I just need some help putting a snapshot listener into the code above as I am also ordering the posts by their timestamp.

Many thanks :)

Comment: It's mostly a matter of using `addSnapshotListener` rather than the `getDocuments` that you have now. Did you try that based on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#swift?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this works. is there any way for it to not go black as it fetches the data?

Comment: "go black" sounds like a UI update problem. Firebase doesn't update your UI, so I can't say where that comes from

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know, but as it fetches new information it reloads the previous UI and it goes black for half a second. Are you aware of any method to solve this?

Comment: None of the code you shared updates the UI in any way, so it's hard to say. It might help if you show your `completion` handler. If you're showing a lot of documents it might be just the amount of work though, in which case you could consider detecting the exact changes in the snapshots and rendering only what was changed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots

Comment: May I suggest a separate question regarding your UI going black? @FrankvanPuffelen answered this question in his comment, which you got working (YAY!) - an additional question about your UI going black would be unrelated to this question and we would need to see a totally separate section of code. That would be well suited for a separate question here on SO.